# Number of cycles in a oriented graph?

Tags: graph-theory

I just computed the number of 3-cycles (as an exercise, generalization could be done for n-cycles) in a *(finite)* non-oriented graph.
I wanted to know if there is any way to compute the number of cycles in an oriented graph.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What method did you use for the non-oriented case?

Comment: By prooving that the number of cycles is $\frac{1}{6}Trace(A^3)$, where $A$ is the Adgacency matrix of the graph. (using the lemma regarding the coefficient of $A^n$ ). If you dont see what i mean, i'll explain it more precisely.

Comment: I do see what you mean, that's the usual method, and it readily adapts to the directed case: $A_{i,j}^k$ is the number of paths of length exactly $k$ between $i$ and $j$ (this is proven by induction). Thus $A_{i,i}^3$ is the number of length $3$ paths returning to $i$. Now the trace sums up these length $3$ cycles, but one has to be careful since each 3-cycles is counted twice for the direction and three time because each cycle is counted once per vertex it contains.
Hence, for the directed case the number of $3$-cycles is $\frac13 Tr(A^3)$ since the direction is already accounted for.